# pause facebook video on scroll

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to pause facebook video on scroll but its not working below is my code. It gives error pause of undefined. Is there any other way?

```
 <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '6296624552155',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v3.2'
      });


  var my_video_player;
      FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {

       if (msg.type === 'video') {
         jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
          console.log('test');
    my_video_player = msg.instance;

           my_video_player.pause() ;

        });
        }

  });



    };


  </script>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

Comment: You didn’t assign any value to `my_video_player` anywhere, so what else other than `undefined` did you expect it to be?

Comment: You missed the part where you actually access the video player instance that is provided via the callback parameter. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api#setup

Comment: I tried     my_video_player = msg.instance; as well, just edited my code above but not working, why that variable not accessible outside? how to stop fb video?

Comment: Your scroll handler function runs in a completely different scope. You need to assign this while `msg` is available - _outside_ of `jQuery(window).scroll(…)`

Comment: so where do i put scroll function and pause it?

Comment: That stays as it is … `my_video_player = msg.instance` simply belongs outside of it.